# Передать данные из кастомного класса в UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Есть кастомный класс:

```
class BaseElement: Codable {

    var userName: String
    var userScore: Int

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userName
        case userScore
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        userName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .userName)
        userScore = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .userScore)
    }
}
```

И есть Extension для UserDefaults:

```
extension UserDefaults {

    func set<T: Encodable>(encodable: T, forKey key: String) {
        if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(encodable) {
            set(data, forKey: key)
        }
    }

    func value<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: String) -> T? {
        if let data = object(forKey: key) as? Data,
            let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data) {
            return value
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Я хочу заполнить этот класс и передать в UserDefaults. Но я не могу обратиться к объектам класса, я могу только применить init(), что мне надо сделать чтобы этот класс заполнить?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сохранять значения и информацию в UserDefaults в любом месте и достать  ту же информацию в любом другом месте. Надо лишь использовать один и тот же стринговый ключ для значений. 
Вы можете попробовать так.

```
let someClass = yourClass.init()
UserDefaults.standard.set(someClass, forKey: "Class")
```